# Mapping multiple resources from one ObjectManager in RestKit

Tags: objective-c, ios, rest, restkit

I'm writing a client for a semi-REST web service (for now it only supports GET requests).

My problem is next. I have one base URL and two types of resources each one on the different resource path.

By this time I have two classes that represent that resources structures, I have two instances of `RKObjectMapping` for mapping each resource type, and I have **two instances** of `RKObjectManager` each one with different mapping. In app I load resources calling `loadObjectsAtResourcePath:` on each instance of `RKObjectManager`.

Can someone suggest how can I improve my code, because I feel that I should use only one instance of `RKObjectManager` as I work with only one web service.

I will be very thankful for any advice, because I've searched a lot and haven't found any solution.

Comment: The base URL is the same and the endpoints are different, right? What is the benefit of using two RKObjectManager instances? why not just use one and pass in the correct mapping for each call?

Comment: I agree with theVurt. Why not just use [RKObjectManager sharedManager]?

Answer (score 2):

In order to use one RKObjectManager, I think you can do something like this:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:somePath 
                                                usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader* loader) {
    // Set the mapping to use for this particular request
    loader.objectMapping = specificObjectMappingRequired;
    loader.delegate = ...
}];
```

See [RKObjectManager reference](http://restkit.org/api/master/Classes/RKObjectManager.html#//api/name/loadObjectsAtResourcePath%3ausingBlock%3a) for more info.